# android: how to store api URL as String resource

Tags: php, android, json, string, url

I'm trying to store some URLs in my `strings.xml` file. I need to work with JSON objects so my URLs are of the form:

`http://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&page=Plaza_de_Espa%C3%B1a_(Madrid)`

I have tried the solutions proposed in some of the StackOverflow forums, i.e, I tried replacing `&` with `%26` but Eclipse marks it as an error.
Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED IT! The URLs have to be written in the folllowing way:

`http://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&amp;action=parse&amp;page=Plaza_de_España_(Madrid)`

That is, replacing `&` with `&amp;`